# android volley TimeoutError

Tags: java, android, node.js, json, android-volley

i prepared a node js webservice that returns a JSON response when i test it with this URL : http://localhost:3000/users?name=ali&password=ali  , it successfully returns a JSON response i setted so i made sure it's working . 
Actually i am trying  to use this webservice in android so i tried to get a JSON response using Volley library in android but i am getting  : com.android.volley.TimeoutError
this is my android code where i am establishing connection and making request :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String URL = "http://196.2.182.69:3000/users";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.e("Rest Response",response.toString());
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Log.e("Rest Response",error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }
```

Notice : i changed 'localhost' with my ip address and i deactivated my firewall

Comment: Is your Apache server up and running? Are you getting a response using postman?

Comment: yes the apache is running i am getting a query wth results from the database table as i see now the problem is about connecting to localhost from the android emulator

Comment: Your emulator should be on the same network as your localhost API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

While accessing localhost API from real device your device must be in the same network or LAN.

Make sure that have you added internet permission in the manifest.

Set `DefaultRetryPolicy` to your request.

```
 objectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
 objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,
 DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
 DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Add above code before this `requestQueue.add(objectRequest);` line.

Comment: still the same error , i get " Rest Response: com.android.volley.TimeoutError " after 30 seconds  by the way i just changed the URL with another one it's returning a response "https://api.myjson.com/bins/kp9wz" but it's not a local URL